# Protractor and xpath to navigate the DOM

Tags: protractor, angularjs-e2e

I'm able to use `cssContainingText()` to look up a grid row, and fetch its id attribute as follows:

```
this.getRowIdByText = function (text) { 
  var sel = '#theReport .ui-grid-viewport .ui-grid-canvas';
  var firstRow = element.all(by.css(sel)).first();
  var gridRows = firstRow.all(by.repeater('(rowRenderIndex, row) in rowContainer.renderedRows track by $index'));

  var result = gridRows.all(by.cssContainingText('div', "COL 1, ROW 1 TEXT CONTENTS")).first();

  var parentId = result.all(by.xpath("./div")); // "./ancestor::div[starts-with(@id, 'id')]"
return parentId.getAttribute("id");
```

but now I'd like to use some `xPath` expression to fetch the related data row, with text value "MY VALUE - COL2, ROW 1" and id="1484316102519-0-uiGrid-0007-cell".

Here is a sample DOM -

```html
<div class="ui-grid-contents-wrapper">
   <div class="grid-menu-stuff">...</div>

   <!-- LEFT-MOST COLUMNS -->
   <div class="grid-container-left">
    <div class="grid-header">...</div>
    <div role="rowgroup" class="ui-grid-viewport">
       
       <div class="ui-grid-canvas">
        <!-- HERE IS THE ROW REPEATER !!! -->
        <div ng-repeat="row in rowContainer.renderedRows">
           <div ui-grid-row="row">
              <div class="ui-grid-cell">
              
                <!-- COL 1, ROW 1 -->
                 <div id="1484316102519-0-uiGrid-0006-cell">
                    <div class="ui-grid-cell-contents" title="COL 1, ROW 1 TEXT CONTENTS"> COL 1, ROW 1 TEXT CONTENTS</div>
                 </div>
                 
              </div>
           </div>   
        </div> 
        <div ng-repeat="row in rowContainer.renderedRows">
           <div ui-grid-row="row">
        <div class="ui-grid-cell">
        
           <!-- COL 1, ROW 2 -->
    <div id="1484316102519-1-uiGrid-0006-cell">
       <div class="ui-grid-cell-contents" title="COL 1, ROW 2 TEXT CONTENTS"> COL 1, ROW 2 TEXT CONTENTS</div>
    </div>
        </div>
           </div>  
          
          
        </div>
        <div ng-repeat="row in rowContainer.renderedRows">
          
        </div>
       </div>   
       
    </div>
   </div>
   
   <!-- DATA ROWS -->
   <div role="rowGroup" class="ui-grid-viewport">
      <div class="ui-grid-canvas">
         <div ng-repeat="row in rowContainer.renderedRows">
            <div ui-grid-row="row">
               <div ui-grid-row="row">
                  <div ng-repeat="col in Columns" id="1484316102519-0-uiGrid-0007-cell">     
                     <div class="ui-grid-cell-contents" title="MY VALUE - COL2, ROW 1">MY VALUE - COL2, ROW 1</div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         
         <div ng-repeat="row in rowContainer.renderedRows">
      <div ui-grid-row="row">
  <div ui-grid-row="row">
     <div ng-repeat="col in Columns" id="1484316102519-1-uiGrid-0007-cell">     
        <div class="ui-grid-cell-contents" title="MY VALUE - COL2, ROW 2">MY VALUE - COL2, ROW 2</div>
     </div>
  </div>
      </div>
         </div>
         
      </div
   </div>
</div>
```

I noticed there is a correlation to the generation of div ID's, so I could probably strip the ID down and infer its related data cell; however, is there a way to use xPath to get the related div ?

Perhaps I'm looking for a sibling element, but I'm not clear how to accomplish this using xpath expressions.

Thanks,
Bob

Comment: Should the `id` values be equal - both "1484316102519-0-uiGrid-0006-cell" and "1484316102519-0-uiGrid-0007-cell"? Or, the 0006 vs 0007 difference is intentional? Thanks.

Comment: @alecxe - Hi Alex. That numeric difference is intentional. It appears to be a pattern. I could probably just calculate that left-most row header to its related data value by stripping out the unique value between "uiGrid" text and "-cell" text...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was very specific the ui-grid, so perhaps this will help someone in the future.
Considering a snippet from the DOM sample above, note that `-1-` represents the row number, `-0006` is the col number:

```
 <!-- COL 1, ROW 2 -->
 <div id="1484316102519-1-uiGrid-0006-cell">
    <div class="ui-grid-cell-contents" title="COL 1, ROW 2 TEXT CONTENTS"> COL 1, ROW 2 TEXT CONTENTS</div>
 </div>
```

I can't first get all rows by repeater:

`var rows myGrid.all(by.repeater('...'));`

Then look up the row by text:

`var result = rows.all(by.cssContainingText('div', 'COL 1, ROW 2 TEXT CONTENTS')).first();`

In my case, I needed the first parent div in order to grab the `id` attrib:

`var parId = result.all(by.xpath("./div"));
var myRowId parId.getAttribute)"id");`

Now having the row id I need, I'll extract the row number so I can get to the data rows of the ui-grid:

`var rowId = myRowId.split('-')[1];`

Now finally I can get the data row :

`var row = this.getDataRows().get(rowId);`    // getDataRows is internal to my function lib.

Once I have `row`, then I'm good to go.

I hope this helps someone in the future.